# iOS 6 Maps API: fleet management and business asset tracking

Tags: ios6-maps

Prior to iOS 6, the ios maps api had restrictions for developers, imposed by Google, some of which are the following:

> 10.9 use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications for or in connection with:
>
> (a) real time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited to turn-by-turn route guidance that is synchronized to the position of a user's sensor-enabled device;
> (b) any systems or functions for automatic or autonomous control of vehicle behavior; or
> (c) **dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking, or similar enterprise applications** (the Google Maps API can be used to track assets (such as cars, buses or other vehicles) as long as the tracking application is made **available to the public without charge**. For example, you may offer a free, public Maps API Implementation that displays real-time public transit or other transportation status information.

(taken from http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html. Apple's Map Kit framework also points there.)

Are these restrictions still in place for ios 6, despite Google no longer providing the maps? Searched the web (and Apple's documentation) for an answer but came up short.

I'm going to build an app that manages a company's rental car fleet (private) and need to use a maps solution for just that. Up until ios 6 I was leaning towards using openlayers + webview but would rather use a native solution if possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe that's not the case, but seems that if you use CoreLocation to obtain vehicle location and then use in somehow for fleet management, you're **not allowed to do that** as far as it contradicts the [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) 4.3:

```
4.3
Apps that use location-based APIs for dispatch, fleet management, or emergency services will be rejected
```

**UPD (1.feb.15):** As lan noticed, this guideline is no longer present in the list.

Comment: As of now it seems that this restriction no longer exists.